# QT Menu window style in Linux

Tags: drop-down-menu, qt4

I stuck with the problem when build menu with QT in ubuntu. 
The menu shows up on the upper left corner as Linux style. How can I change this into window like style like this one.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-menus.html

thanks you,

Comment: If you are using QMainWindow, it tries to mimic your desktop environment, and that is how the desktop environment works.  It's likely that to change it, you'll have to build a main window yourself and set the menu bar where you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks Huitt, would you give a little bit more detail about that, references or something. I'm a lab rat in Qt, ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some one got the same problem, simple solution can be obtained by disable global control menu in linux. There are several way to do this. You can refer here and there in

https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu